# 'Remove' all item from a cart

Tags: mobile, user-behavior, buttons, ux-integration

I am not very good in ux and I hope someone help me out with ideas. I am working on a mobile app

[image]

The user can remove the item by sliding the item to his left. The problem is in case that he has many items and he want to remove all items by clicking one button. Where I can post this button? This is my first question.

My second question is how to display this button? I am thinking about a trash button, but this will be confuse the user.

I am thinking also about select items with checkbox. 
I am confused. What I should do?

Comment: Why not just put "Delete" right next to "Remise." It doesn't have to be fancy, or "cutting edge." Just straight forward! And why would you want to allow all to delete? That's only calling for the user to abandon the cart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not add this button in the first place.

Reason: It adds visual noise and usually little value. Having insights from multiple eCommerce sites I can say that deleting many items is rare. If users do use the cart for saving and/or comparing items it's a bit more likely.

Make sure you have tracking implemented to see how many items are added and deleted per session. You can still add 'remove all' if data suggests that it will be used.

Swipe to delete is a well known, commonly used pattern in native eCommerce apps. It's also fast to use. A good idea is to invest time into building an UNDO functionality. If a user accidentally deleted an item she can still undo (better than an annoying question "Are you sure to delete this item?").

Answer (score 1):

Should an average User have up to 5-6 items in the basket and it would be a not very common action, **I would not add "Remove all"** at all. It would just clutter the interface.

The other thing, however, is **if they will know that swiping an item would remove it** from the basket. I think this is what I would try to do, as I would believe that there must be an option to remove such item, but I think it is worth **testing** to confirm the pattern with your Users. You could add a "swipe an item left to remove from the basket" if they do not know though.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the previous answer, if deleting items by sliding items to the left (which is an easy and fast action) I would not clutter the interface with another button.

On the other hand make sure to mention at some point that the actions of deleting items by sliding to the left is available.